# How do I change an object in a form's properties using a function?

Tags: c#

Let's say you're trying to set a label's text. By doing it, you call a function SetText(labelname, "texthere"). What would the SetText 'header' be?

I'm trying:

```
private void SetText(object foo, string bar)
```

but that doesn't work

edit: I have this:

```
private void SetText(Control thing, string text)
{
if (this.InvokeRequired)
{
SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(SetText);
Invoke(d, new object[] { text });
}
else
{
thing.Text = text;
}
}
```

But it says something about invalid number of parameters. What do I need to change?

Comment: Header?! What do you mean? Are you trying to call the SetText from inside the FOrm's calss or from outside?

Comment: @Zarathos I think he means what would the method prototype be?

Comment: btw it is not called header but Method Signature: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_signature#Method_Signature

Comment: You're obviously missing the control in your invoke: `Invoke(d, new object[] { thing, text });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Control class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.aspx) instead of Object, as the former defines the base class for controls (components with visual representation) and exposes Text property.

```
private void SetText(Control control, String text)
{
    control.Text = text;
}
```

Like this, you don't need to box/cast the Object. Otherwise you should also specify the type of the object as you could pass a TextBox, a Label and so on...

Answer (score 0):

Probably becuase you're referencing the wrong object, try:

```
private void SetText(ref object foo, string bar)
```

Note the `ref` keyword.